# Javascript -design text in console

Tags: javascript, console

hello i am trying to implement something like this in console.

[image]

when user opens browser console message like this must show up

how can it be done?

(screenshot from Facebook.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style console.log() outputs for example in Chrome with CSS

Here is an example:

```js
console.log('%c this is styled with CSS', 'color:red; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold');
```

Comment: thank you! correct!